# Copy directories on schedule linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, sh

I am looking for help with a script that will allow me to copy the contents of a directory, or the whole directory to another directory on a schedule or when new files arrive in the source.

For example:

```
/stuff/folder1/file.txt
```

Copy to:

```
/stuff/folder2/file.txt
```

either when new files arrive or on a recurring schedule.

I do use a Centos machine.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? Share the code you have so far. Please note that this is a place to ask specific questions about issues that arise in the implementation of stuff. This is not a general tutorial forum. You may want to google the term "linux file alteration monitor" though.

Comment: I'd have a look at e.g. `inotify`.

Comment: for inotify i was trying this- 
/media/_data/test/ IN_CLOSE_WRITE,IN_CREATE,IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE cp -r /media/_data/test /media/data/test2 

but I'm not sure i have it correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following program to update `folder2` whenever you save new files or update `folder1`:

```
while inotifywait -r -e modify -e move -e create -e delete; do
    cp -r /stuff/folder1/. /stuff/folder2/
done
```

For the schedule thing I would add `cp -r /stuff/folder1/. /stuff/folder2/` into a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron_job). Instead of `cp` you can also use [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync). Please also have a look on the [manpage of inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait).

**Note:** The above script will start the copy after the first file was altered inside the directory `folder1`. If you modify many files in folder1 in the same time, you might want to put a `sleep` command inside the while loop. But in this case it is better to add the copy command at the end of the program which alters the files of `folder1`.

Comment: so this will run the copy any time a file is modified, moved, created or deleted? will it know a file is being written before it starts the copy?

Comment: The description of ``modify`` says: "A watched file or a file within a watched directory was written to.". So yes, the event is fired after the modification (have a look in the manpage for more details).

Comment: thanks for the answer.
will adding this command after the cp -r command write out to a log file
`echo $file >> /var/log/inotify` so it would look like this?

Comment: `while inotifywait -r -e modify -e move -e create -e delete; do
    cp -r /stuff/folder1/. /stuff/folder2/
    echo $file >> /var/log/inotify;
done`

Comment: Do not understand, what you want to reach with your logging/want you want to log... Do you want to log the modified file after the copy-command?

Comment: i wanted to log let me know every time it runs the cp command in the script - or if it fails or some sort of error pops up